# Regular expression refactoring

Tags: regex

Is there such thing as automated regular expression refactoring?

I'm wondering whether there is an online service or utility that can understand and simplify and/or optimise a regex.

e.g.

`^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]$` → `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$`

(Obviously this is an abstract example)

Comment: I guess it's just as hard as abstract mathematical formula refactoring. Some transformations are easy to make (and easy to prove correct). I doubt there's a tool that can do more than what is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are automata, you can use an algorithm designed to build deterministic finite automaton, it will refactor the original automaton to a simpler one.

I do not know a programming language implementation but you can get inspired with [Nondeterministic finite automaton Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton).

Comment: Tranlasting a FSM into a regex is actually not _that_ easy and could be quite wasteful.

Comment: For example, the language "all symbols occur an even number of times" translates directly to regex with linear overhead in the size of the alphabet, to a FSM with exponential overhead and to regex through a FSM with something along the lines of `O(n^(2^n))`.

Comment: The aforementioned language is indeed regular. Its minimal DFS is a hypercube and its regex is of the form `^(?=[^a]*(a[^a]*a[^a]*)*)(?=[^b]* ... [^z]*)*)$`

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, I have already removed my comment. It's easier to put in DFA states than put in regex.

Comment: You could try to build a regex for "binary number divisible by three". The one generated from the DFS is actually not too large - `(0|1(01*0)*1)*`. The one for 5 is a bit bigger but I don't think I can beat it. On the other hand, the one for 4 is a bit wasteful.

Comment: @JanDvorak nop, the moment I commented it, it shows up the answer... just begin to work on it.

Comment: @xiaoyi you have a tool for generating regexes from FSMs? Can I have one?

Comment: @JanDvorak I wrote one according to the textbook, but it only generates unreadable super super long expression....

Comment: @xiaoyi yeah, that's what I meant by `n^(2^n)`. Enumerating all paths in a general graph is a bad idea.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes. but no matter how the expression looks, as long as it being minimized with myhill-nerode theorem, the performance is the same. Very interesting field of math.

Comment: @xiaoyi I don't know the theorem. Could it answer the original question?

Comment: @xiaoyi I've looked it up. Note that it minimizes DFAs, not regexes.

Comment: @xiaoyi Showing that a state machine recognizing a language would need an infinite number of states is actually a very nice idea. This theorem also shows that all "equal to x modulo m with input in base b" languages are regular.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, and not hard to think it in DFA states. but really painful to put it to RE

Comment: I'm wondering - which regex engines actually _build_ a DFA when compiling a regex, or even minimise it?

Comment: @xiaoyi then you didn't support backreferences, am I right? `^(.*)\1$` is not a regular language.

Comment: no, it's something beyond DFA. My one only support basic syntax, like Kleene closure, group etc.

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks, it was part of my Compiler-compiler project. It's really great experience with some fundamental technologies.

Answer (score -1):

This may be  useful ( I have not tried it yet ) 
http://www.myregextester.com/

Hey I tried this

Use it as follows

1. pasted the following code under "Source Text"
   AA111
   AA111AA111
2. Select 'CHARSET: optimize charset' in 'TOOLS' drop down
3. Paste the regex pattern string and hit 'GO'

Comment: It failed to optimise `^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]$` to `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}` or vice versa. It didn't transform either. Perhaps it didn't find the regex worth optimizing?

Comment: If it doesn't do _this_, then what _does_ it do? Is the checkbox just a placebo?

Comment: I tried this it is optimizing the regex. I updated that in my answer

Comment: Pasting the pattern into the input that appears when you select `charset` produces incorrect results. It expects a character class in there, not a regex. Even then, the results are unpredictable.

Comment: The number range generator tool looks promising until you actually try it out. the results are terrible. The regex for `1000 - 9999` is fourteen lines long and seems to enumerate all 90 cases of the first two digits. It should be `[1-9][0-9]{3}` or `0*[1-9][0-9]{3}`.

Comment: The generated regex for passwords is actually relatively reasonable (even though it _could_ be much better).

Comment: The word list regex generator is actually quite nice (although it still doesn't do _all_ optimisation).

Comment: I'm not the asker, and I don't think this tool is useful for _optimizing_ regexes. I guess I could write a better one.

Comment: Thanks @shiva, but I don't think this is the right tool for the job.